# Which Minkowski metric $\eta$ is to be used for computing $W_i^{\mu\nu}W^i_{\mu\nu}$ in the electroweak Lagrangian?

Tags: differential-geometry, euler-lagrange-equation

The electroweak Lagrangian before symmetry breaking is [defined as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_interaction):

$$L_{ew} = L_g + L_f + L_h + L_y$$

where the $L_g$ portion concerns 4 identically-structured vector fields

$$\vec B = [B^0,B^1,B^2,B^3]\\
\vec W_0 = [W_0^0,W_0^1,W_0^2,W_0^3]\\
\vec W_1 = [W_1^0,W_1^1,W_1^2,W_1^3]\\
\vec W_2 = [W_2^0,W_2^1,W_2^2,W_2^3]$$

By definition,

$$L_g = -\frac{1}{4}(B^{\mu\nu}B_{\mu\nu}) -\frac{1}{4}tr(W_0^{\mu\nu}W^0_{\mu\nu})-\frac{1}{4}tr(W_1^{\mu\nu}W^1_{\mu\nu})-\frac{1}{4}tr(W_2^{\mu\nu}W^2_{\mu\nu})$$

where

$$B^{ij} = \frac{dB^j}{dx^i} - \frac{dB^i}{dx^j}$$

and $W_i^{\mu\nu}$ is a $4x4$ matricx whose elements are defined by

$$W^{ab}_i=\frac{d}{dx^a}W^b_i - \frac{d}{dx^b}W^a_i - igW^a_iW^b_i + igW^b_iW^a_i$$

The lower-index $W^0_{\mu\nu}$ (and $B_{\mu\nu}$) are computed using the relation

$$W_{ab} = \sum_{i,j}^4 \eta_{ib}W^{ji}\eta_{aj}$$

where $\eta$ is the Minkowski metric

$$\eta = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

I am unclear about *which* $\eta$ metric is to be used here, as there are 2 possible $\eta$, the alternative being

$$\eta^* = \begin{bmatrix} -1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

1. Does it matter which version of $\eta$ or $\eta^*$ is used in the computation of $L_g$, in the scheme of the overall $L_{ew}$ computation?
2. Is any other metric other than $\eta$ allowed in the Lagrangian?

Comment: I don't know but it is surprising that you jump right into that subject without being aware of the [sign convention](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_convention).

Comment: @KurtG. thank you, I am aware of the 2 equivalent sign conventions, but not sure which one is  being used here. These are some really complex models, so i would like to try and build the castle first, before exploring it, so to speak.

Comment: Wikipedia may not be the best source to start learning the electroweak Lagrangian. I am sure that we can define a reputable source fot this as being one where your question would not even arise. Steven Weinberg's works should fit.

Answer (score 1):

The computational result of

$$W_{ab}=\sum_{i,j}^4\eta_{ib}W^{ji}\eta_{aj}$$

is naturally invariant whether (+,-,-,-) or (-,+,+,+) is used as $\eta$, ie.

[image]

lowered using (+,-,-,-) gives us

[image]

and likewise using (+,-,-,-) gives us the identical

[image]

Thus, there is no operational significance to which $\eta$ is adopted for purposes of index-lowering a tensor.

The general component-wise result of $\sum_{i,j}^4 W_{ij}W^{ij}$ is thus the matrix multiplication yielding

[image]